# Are there any "modern" SCSI devices?

Tags: scsi

I'm building a new computer in an old computer case.  The old computer case came with a Centronic [50-pin SCSI to IDE adapter](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5563767A), and I was thinking about leaving it in the case's 5.25" drive bay, purely for aesthetic purposes.

This got me thinking if there were any "modern" SCSI devices that could be plugged into it? I was thinking along the same lines as USB [personal fans](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07K2YDF34) or [mug warmers](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08SP9L7BX).  If it's a device that actually has some technical use that would be good as well!

Here's a photo because why not:

[image: SCSI to IDE]

Comment: I note that SCSIDE devices (which is what I suspect you have) are surprisingly expensive on the likes of eBay. Which is why I have just the one, instead of as many as I would like…

Comment: SCSI stuff is probably so expensive on Ebay because all companies need to collect whatever they can to keep their "the project for replacing this server should have been completed a decade ago"-server running...

Comment: That is not an IDE to SCSI adapter. That is simply a drive bay for swapping IDE drives. It just happens to use whatever connector available to allow passing of IDE bus and drive power to the drive.

Comment: @Justme ah ok.  There isn't much information on the web about this, that's why I linked to the patent on Google Patents.  It looks like the drives themselves were SCSI though?  It's adapting something to IDE.

Comment: No, they are IDE drives connectes to IDE bus. You are missing the box where the drive goes into, and it has a matching connector.

Comment: @Justme ohhh ok I see.  Thanks for the info I really appreciate it!

Comment: They're not electrically compatible, but SAS drives are still used in servers. You could probably convert them to traditional SCSI.

Comment: Aside from SAS mentioned above, SCSI is still very widely used in a number of other places without the old SPI hardware. FCP, SRP, iSCSI, UAS, and ATAPI are all used almost daily all over the world, and all consist of SCSI’s high-level protocol tunneled over some other low-level protocol.

Comment: The SCSI protocol forms the basis of the Fibre Channel Protocol (FCP, as mentioned by @AustinHemmelgarn) which is widely used in high-end and very high speed (up to 128Gbps) storage networking environments (SAN).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot plug or connect any SCSI devices.

That is not an IDE to SCSI adapter.

That is a drive bay for quickly exchanging IDE drives to a computer.

The connector is simply a passive connector for passing through IDE bus signals and power supplies into the box where the IDE drive is in.

Due to the connector having IDE signals and 5V and 12V power supplies, it will damage any SCSI equipment connected to it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I wasn't aware that I was missing pieces to this thing!  Looks like it'll just stay around for aesthetic purposes as I originally intended.

Comment: woah +1 for the damage warning

Answer (score 4):

There's the [SCSI2SD](http://www.codesrc.com/mediawiki/index.php/SCSI2SD) which lets you use an SD card as a SCSI hard drive. Other than that, I'm not aware of any recent SCSI devices. Also, SCSI doesn't provide power, making it less suitable for fans or mug warmers.

You can, of course, use a SCSI CD ROM drive as a cup holder.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm very unfamiliar with SCSI. I wasn't even aware/didn't do the research to find out that it doesn't provide power.  That will definitely limit the amount of "gadgets" that I was thinking may be available. A cupholder might be a good addition to the rig 

Comment: If you want it only for the aesthetics - you can rewire the internal side for power, or, usb, or whatever, all you need is a matching connector that you can then wire up to a usb socket that you can use for your mug warmer, vibrator, or death ray... just don't overdo the power draw.

Answer (score 4):

As is mentioned in the comments this is a bay that accepts PATA devices in suitable caddies. using the 50-way beam connector to connect the caddy to the ATA bus and power.

As the bay takes up a half-height 5.25" bay, the only devices it will accept will be smaller than that, mostly 3.5" drives. with a suitable caddy.

you're better off mounting a "cup-holder", 12V outlet, or a front IO panel. in that spot.